# Cannot fetch data from Firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to get data from Firebase's et_events collection and have the events displayed on the frontend.

I wrote the following code in the events.js file and tried to get the event information from Firebase, but I couldn't get it.

```js
export const actions = {
  fetchAllEvents: async ({ dispatch, commit }, eventIds) => {
    // TODO: fetch events from firestore
    console.log("start")
    const eventsSnap = await getDocs(query(eventsRef, where(documentId(), 'et_events', eventIds)))
    const events = await Promise.all(
      eventsSnap.docs.map(async snap => {
        const organization = await dispatch('fetchOrganization', snap.data().organizationId)
        return {
          id: snap.id,
          organization,
          isEvent: true,
          ...snap.data(),
        }
      }),
    )
    events.sort((a, b) => {
      if(a.startDT > b.startDT) return 1;
      if(a.startDT < b.startDT) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    events.splice(1, 0, {
      isEvent: false,
      imgUrl: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/eventomy/statics/thumbnails/tutorial.png',
      title: 'Eventomyを始めよう',
    })


    // remove code above and put your code instead
    commit(SET_EVENTS, events)
  },
}
```

Also, I don't quite understand the meaning of "dispatch", "commit", and "eventsSnap" in this code. Can anyone tell me?

The full code is published below.

```js
const SET_EVENTS = 'SET_EVENTS'

export const state = () => ({
  events: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_EVENTS: (state, events) => {
    state.events = events
  },
}

export const getters = {
  allEvents(state) {
    return state.events
  },
}


// import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
export const actions = {
  fetchAllEvents: async ({ dispatch, commit }, eventIds) => {
    // TODO: fetch events from firestore
    console.log("start")
    const eventsSnap = await getDocs(query(eventsRef, where(documentId(), 'et_events', eventIds)))
    const events = await Promise.all(
      eventsSnap.docs.map(async snap => {
        const organization = await dispatch('fetchOrganization', snap.data().organizationId)
        return {
          id: snap.id,
          organization,
          isEvent: true,
          ...snap.data(),
        }
      }),
    )
    events.sort((a, b) => {
      if(a.startDT > b.startDT) return 1;
      if(a.startDT < b.startDT) return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    events.splice(1, 0, {
      isEvent: false,
      imgUrl: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/eventomy/statics/thumbnails/tutorial.png',
      title: 'Eventomyを始めよう',
    })


    // remove code above and put your code instead
    commit(SET_EVENTS, events)
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi @becko , what seems to be the error on this code? Also, the `eventsSnap` seems to be not right. Check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) on how to fetch data from Firestore.

Comment: tnx mr Marc Anthony.

Comment: events are not  displaying on the frontend UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure of what you want to achieve on your code. Based on your statement above, you just want to get the documents data of the `et_events` collection. Here are some ways to get data from `et_events`.

To get all the documents from `et_events`:

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "et_events"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  // Do something here...
});
```

To get filtered documents, use `where()` query:

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "et_events"), where("<FIELDNAME>", "==", "<FIELDVALUE>"));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  // Do something here....
});
```

If you know the document ID of a specific document:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "et_events", "<DOCUMENTID>");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  // Do something here...
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

---

For more information, you may checkout [Get data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_2).